# Select element with jQuery without using ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

So I have a list of elements in an array. I'd like to add a jQuery toggle event to each element and pass in two functions as parameters. This is what I have so far, though it's giving me errors, saying that e (the Event Object) is undefined inside moveToSelected and moveToUnselected.

```
// Getting my array
var selected = document.getElementsByClassName("selected_style");

// The two functions to toggle between:

function moveToSelected(e) {
    style = e.target;
    style.className = "selected_style";
    $('#selected-style').append(e.target);
}

function moveToUnselected(e) {
    style = e.target
    style.className = "unselected_style";
    $('#unselected-style').append(e.target);
}

// Going through the array and adding a toggle event to each element.
for(var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
    var element = $(unselected[i]);
    element.toggle(moveToSelected, moveToUnselected);
}
```

HTML, as requested:

```
<ul id="selected-style">
    <li>
      Some Style
    </li>
    <li class="selected_style">
      Style
    </li>
    <li class="selected_style">
      Style
    </li>
    <li class="selected_style">
      Style
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhm, why aren't you using jQuery, this is already built in ?

```
$('.selected_style').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected_style unselected_style');

    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected_style') ) {
        $('#selected-style').append(this);
    } else {
        $('#unselected-style').append(this);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/o8exg4hd/)

Comment: That worked! Thanks, I thought that .toggleClass only changed the class and didn't have any other functionality. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The vanilla javascript solution for future viewers. No jQuery required. This is effectively the same script as the accepted answer, without all the overhead of jQuery.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/fxu4q7km/6/))

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var selected = document.getElementById('selected-style');
    var unselected = document.getElementById('unselected-style');
    var items = document.querySelectorAll('.selected_style'), item;
    for (var i = 0; item = items[i]; i++) {
        item.onclick = function(){
            if(this.className.indexOf('unselected_style') >= 0) {
                this.className = this.className.replace(' unselected_style','');
                this.className += ' selected_style';
                selected.appendChild(this);
            } else {
                this.className = this.className.replace(' selected_style','');
                this.className += ' unselected_style';
                unselected.appendChild(this);
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

Comment: Not really the same as the jQuery approach; this approach assumes `getElementsByClassName` and `addEventListener` are both supported by the browser.

Comment: Internet Explorer 8 is an enterprise standard, and supports neither. This is precisely why jQuery has had such a profound impact on the JavaScript community. Don't despise it - embrace it :)